# Apache Shiro isAuthenticated returns true after Tomcat restart

Tags: java, tomcat, shiro, catalina

I have a webapp deployed with Tomcat (8.0.32) and the login/logout operations work fine with each redeployment. However they do not work so well if I stop Catalina without redeploying the webapp (`./catalina.sh stop` and then `./catalina.sh start` without any changes to the contents of the webapp folder). What happens is that method `org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject.isAuthenticated()` returns `true` right after the server starts **but before the new login operation takes place**.

More specifically, my implementation of `javax.servlet.Filter.doFilter` starts with the following line:

```
if(org.apache.shiro.SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated()) ...
```

which returns true right after the server restarted but before the new login. Shiro's version is 1.3.0.

Therefore I was wondering if I am missing something, e.g. is there any operation that must be performed before, or is this the wrong way to use this method? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how your Shiro configuration looks like but depending on your implementation Shiro by default sets a cookie which still can be valid after your server restarts.

Depending on your SessionManager implementation, you can set a `globalSessionTimeout` and `sessionValidationInterval`. The default session timeout is set to [1800000L](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.2.2/apidocs/constant-values.html#org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.AbstractSessionManager.DEFAULT_GLOBAL_SESSION_TIMEOUT) (30 minutes). See [AbstractSessionManager](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/AbstractSessionManager.html#DEFAULT_GLOBAL_SESSION_TIMEOUT) and [DefaultWebSessionManager](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/session/mgt/AbstractValidatingSessionManager.html#DEFAULT_SESSION_VALIDATION_INTERVAL). Example implementation:

```
sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
# Session timeout token_ttl_ms = 14 days
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout = 1209600000
# Session valdiation = 15 minutes
sessionManager.sessionValidationInterval = 900000
```

If you don't want to use any cookie, you can disable it by setting the following property in your SecurityManager config and skip the session management by the SessionManager completely:

```
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled = false
```